# How to merge branches in VSS?

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

i'm trying to merge a branch in Visual SourceSafe 6.

Here you see the bug in the 'main line' code base:

[image]

A hotfix branch was created, and the file was fixed:

[image]

Now it's time to merge the hotfix back into the main line development. i select the file i want to merge, and hit the **SourceSafe** → **Merge Branches...** menu option:

[image]

With the merge complete, i confirm that the main line now contains the hotfix, which it does not:

[image]

So what is the proper technique to merge branches in Visual SourceSafe 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the file you want to merge **into**, i.e. the mainline file.  Then execute Merge Branches.  In the dialog, select the file you want to merge **from**, i.e. the hotfix file.

Comment: i thought that merging branches would merge the branches, rather than leaving the branches branched. But it is the answer to the question - and you can't be blamed for VS design.

Answer (score 0):

Select the file in trunk, execute merge branches, in the dialog, select branch file, click merge.